# Setting Lat Lng Values into Hidden Field Before Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Google Maps Api (including autocomplete) for users to write an address into a form field, and then finding the latitude and longitude values of that entered address.

Now, I would like to send those values back to the form (hidden fields) to submit to the database.
The backend is all set up, I'm just not sure how to do it with on the client. I'm thankful for any help!

My Code
Ruby:

```
<div id="form>
  <%= f.text_field :location, onFocus: "geolocate", id: "autocomplete" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :latitude, id: "lat" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :longitude, id: "lng" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn" %>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
    // next line creates asynchronous request
    geocoder.geocode( { 'autocomplete': address}, function(results, status) {
      // and this is function which processes response
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $("#lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        $("#lng").val(results[1].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  var placeSearch, autocomplete;

  function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }
  }

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
          geolocation));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? you're setting the hidden fields in the right way, and when submitting the form you can save those values in your db the way you need. What are you missing?

Comment: Thanks for viewing the code.  I'm not getting the lat/lng values to save...

Answer (score 2):

You could put a callback to submit the form on successful geolocation if that is what you are trying to do using `$("#form").submit();` [docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    $("#lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
    $("#lng").val(results[1].geometry.location.lng());
    $("#form").submit();
}
```

Comment: thanks! I think this is getting there.  However in my console these values aren't being INSERT INTO the db. The location name is, but not the lat and lng values...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the form: you should put lat and long hidden field with the form builder like this:

```
<div id="form>
  <%= f.text_field :location, onFocus: "geolocate", id: "autocomplete" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :latitude, id: "lat" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :longitude, id: "lng" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn" %>
</div>
```